# Bullied boy given immense powers by an alien race who destroys the human race

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking to identify a short story I read in a sci-fi anthology as a child, about an angry, bullied somewhat misanthropic boy who is given immense near-omnipotent powers by an alien intelligence. I read this in English, sometime in the late 1990s/early 2000s. He goes on to use this power to destroy the human race, which causes him to age terribly in a very short amount of time. At the end of the story he is a lonely old man stripped of the powers he held briefly, and is alone on an isolated Earth. The aliens then proceed to invade Earth.

Comment: Sorry, I should add that I read this in English, sometime in the late 1990s/early 2000s so anytime before then.

Comment: It appears you created two accounts, you might want to look into [merging](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous) them.

Comment: Also since it's never been linked to you yet, you might have more success looking at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) which might help you add more details.

Comment: This question seems similar.   https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141303/1970s-1980s-childrens-sf-anthology-british-identification

Comment: @M. A. Golding - thanks for linking the two queries. The extra detail on Gerard's description sounds in line with my own hazy memories. It would definitely have been in the mid-1980's I read 'my' story. Hopefully we'll get a positive ID yet!

Comment: The powers don't cause him to age, he is prompted to enact revenge on various people he is goaded into thinking wronged him (such as "the government didn't help him" and he has a vision of the government buildings being washed away by a tidal wave), but rather he is left the only man alive and the aliens then cause him to artificially age rapidly, saying "we aren't monsters, after all".

Comment: @user71888 does that extra detail sound familiar?

Comment: @Moo Yes, he was definitely the last man left alive, drawing patterns in the dust on his own. Between this, and the 'coma' story in your post, we're definitely on the right track. That was was some bleak sh*t to be reading as a young 'un, probably why it's left an impression on me 30 years on.

Comment: Yeah, I'm pretty sure we are all thinking of the same story, Moo's extra details sound right. Are you both UK-based? I'm Irish so I wonder if it's a UK-based anthology. Also I'm pretty sure I got the book in the small second hand bookshop in my hometown so could well be 70s/80s.

Comment: @Gerard Irish, too, as it happens. so more than likely a UK imprint. hardly a home-grown one :-)

Comment: @Gerard someone was successful in finding this book in response to my similar question - its "Science Fantasy Stories" by Cathay Books, ISBN 0-86178-485-5

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The story [according to Moo's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/179081/story-identification-boy-goes-into-multiple-comas-but-wakes-up-in-reality-durin/181172#comment489914_179081) is "Master of All The World" from [Science Fantasy Stories](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Science-Fantasy-Stories-Various/dp/0861784855): a child is given the ability to destroy the world by an alien race.