# Short story about space sheep and an inflatable doll

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, space

Sometime almost two decades ago, I read a really disturbing science fiction story.

It was about a rancher who lived alone with his blow up doll on some deserted planet.

He took care of (and milked?) some "space sheep" that I believe had some sort of spiky fur.

The overtones were fairly depressing, that the man cared for both his sheep but longed for human contact, and he would play dress up with his blowup doll after finishing his duties around the ranch.

The pinnacle of the story was that a space sheep manages to enter his cabin and its spiky fur pops the blowup doll, sending the rancher into a saddened frenzy. He shoots the offending space sheep, causing the herd to get mad and murder him, through suffocation, I believe.

Comment: Have you checked the list of [Hugo Award winners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hugo_Award_for_Best_Short_Story)?

Comment: I have nothing to add here, I just like the subject line.

Comment: This is possibly about the book your short story came from - sadly, title not found, but it might help someones memory... https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/566586/#post-2094756

Comment: @user14111 wins the internet tonight!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Old MacDonald had a space farm* by M. S. Goodall - a isolated farmer of Wrigglets goes mad with loneliness. It's been included in [Science Fantasy Stories](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Science-Fantasy-Stories-Various/dp/0861784855).

The [sffchronicles.com thread](https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/566586/) from the comments links to previous [scifi.stackexchange.com question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141303/1970s-1980s-childrens-sf-anthology-british-identification) and someone has been been searching for it on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmytongue/comments/9h3h2b/tomt_book_science_fiction_anthology_from_late_80s/).