# Short story where aliens give boy super powers which he uses to destroy the world, dies alone

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens, apocalypse

I'm actually trying to pin down an anthology and this is the only story I can remember being definitely in it.

A boy (maybe called Christopher) is visited by aliens who agree to carry out his every wish.  He begins small but eventually is destroying cities with huge tsunamis that are being brought into being by the aliens, as per his request.  I seem to remember he knows he's doing it and there was an angle in the story explaining his nihilistic behaviour.

At the end the boy is on top of a hill looking out over the devastation he has caused (the Earth is now dead) and writes in the dust at his feet something along the lines of "I WAS (his name, possibly Christopher but not too sure).  The aliens depart and the final scene is them justifying their behaviour by stating that they are not monsters but just looking for a home.

If I can identify the story then I should be able to use isfdb.com to pin down the anthology.

The story is from the 1990s or earlier.

Comment: Found it!                https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133178/bullied-boy-given-immense-powers-by-an-alien-race-who-destroys-the-human-race?rq=1